# Save a list in preferences

Tags: java, preferences

I need to save a list of strings using Java preferences but there isn't any API to save a list. Am I missing anything? Is there a common way to do it?

Comment: I'm not working with android

Comment: But you can have a Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean `java.util.prefs.Preferences`? There is no built-in solution, just store them under keys (e.g.) `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. and write some methods to simplify working with such nodes. Alternately, consider using a library such as [Apache Config](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#List_handling) or [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).